# Moq C# call method to test

Tags: c#, testing, moq

I'm new to Testing in C# and I'm trying to test a method that only increments some passed integer value (when it's called with 5 it returns 6). What am I doing wrong here? `result` is always 0.

```
public void TestMethod2()
        {
            //Act
            int numberToCheck = 5;
            mock.CallBase = true;
            mock.Setup(x => x.CalculateTest(numberToCheck)).Returns(6);
            int result = mock.Object.CalculateTest(It.IsAny<int>());
            int expected = numberToCheck + 1;

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test appears to be a little pointless. It looks like your mocking the very thing you want to test. Normally you mock everything else around the bit you want to test a bit like this:

```
//This is normally something like a repository that you link to from a service.
//You want the repo to return mocked data so you can see what your service method
//actually does in a set circumstance.
private Mock<ISomethingEffectingYourTestsToMock> _myMockObject; 
private IMyServiceUnderTest _sut;

[TestInitialize]
public void Init()
{
    _myMockObject = new Mock<ISomethingEffectingYourTestToMock>(); //mock
    _sut = new MyServiceUnderTest(your parameters); //real instance
}

[TestMethod]
public void SomeOtherMethod_should_return_23_if_input_is_20()
{
    var mockRepoOutput = 6;
    this._myMockObject.Setup(r => r.someMethod(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(mockRepoOutput);

    var inputParam = 20;
    var expectedResult = 23;

    var result = _sut.SomeOtherMethod(inputParam);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);
}
```

Something to consider when starting to write a suite of unit tests are things like common        mock data, mock setup etc. You can save a lot of time if you don't have to setup mock data objects in every test and instead can just call a method to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful.